# Jira Software Server Upgrade Path From 7.0.10 to 9.2.0

Tags: jira, upgrade

I want to upgrade my Jira Software Server version. How do I upgrade from 7.0.10 to 9.2.0 installed in Windows Server 2016 environment? I request your help.

Kind regards.

Answer (score 1):

I guess I would go to 8.0.latest, then perhaps to 8.20.latest and then 9.2.latest. I'd carefully check the supported platforms for each version
looking at OS, JVM, database versions. Not a simple job but doable

https://confluence.atlassian.com/adminjiraserver/supported-platforms-938846830.html